QGIS Coordinated Conversion MGRS: Showing Invalid
I have installed the Lat Lon Tools Plugins in QGIS 3.34.4. When I am trying to convert the Lat Lon to MGRS , it is showing invalid:

On adding the print statement i get to know about that error is coming on OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow Please check the image.

You need to specify at least the exact QGIS version used and the exact plugin version installed and what value exactly did you insert in what field of the Coordinate Conversion dialog window.

Tell also if you are using some special locale.

There is no issue using QGIS 3.38.2 and Lat Lon Tools plugin 3.7.1 on Windows 10:

Try if the issue occurs using a currently supported QGIS version with a new QGIS user profile and the latest Lat Lon Tools plugin version available ensuring to restore the Lat Lon Tools plugin settings to default values.

I have added print statement in Lat Lon Tool Plugins and it is showing some OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow related error.

Instead of showing <osgeo.osr.CoordinateTransformation; proxy of None >this message , it should display message like <osgeo.osr.CoordinateTransformation; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OSRCoordinateTransformationShadow *' at 0x0000018C68F68660> >. Can you help with this error

You need to report the issue to the plugin author https://github.com/hamiltoncj/qgis-latlontools-plugin/
